# Pull Column data values from sys.columns from a database having same table structure

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am dealing with the situation in sql server where a database contains the multiple tables with similar table name (ex total_0122, total_0622) and same column. I wanted to calculate the percentage difference from all those tables by taking particular columns data.
My approch is

1. list all the tables present in the database with name like %Total_%
2. Then concatenate/join the all the tables together
3. Read the table content
4. lastly find the percentage diffrence.

I am able to list all the tables present in the database and able to concatenate it which is step 1 and 2. for which i have performed

```
''' SELECT
   sys.columns.name AS ColumnName,
   tables.name AS TableName
   FROM
   sys.columns
   JOIN sys.tables ON
   sys.columns.object_id = tables.object_id
   WHERE
   sys.tables.name LIKE '%total_%
```

which gives me an output as

```
 ColumnName    TableName
 email         total_0122
 country       total_0122
 revenue       total_0122
 email         total_0622
 country       total_0622
 revenue       total_0622
```

I am not able to figure out how to read those tables into one table along with the column values (email, country, revenue...)
I am new sql. Any help will be appreciated. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a query from your select. Assuming:

```
create table total_0122 ( x int, y int );
insert into total_0122 values (1,1);
create table total_0129 ( x int, y int );
insert into total_0122 values (2,2),(3,3);
```

Your query returns:

```
ColumnName  TableName
x   total_0122
y   total_0122
x   total_0129
y   total_0129
```

Now you can construct a new query like:

```
select coalesce(origin, 'Total'), count(x), count(y)
from (
  select 'total_0122' as origin, x, y from total_0122
  union
  select 'total_0129' as origin, x, y from total_0129
) as t
group by grouping sets ((origin),());
```

I.e. for each of the tables in your previos result, you create one leg in the union.

By using a grouping set with origin and the empty set, we get count's for individual tables, as well as for the total.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kDhPw9Vq)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for dynamic SQL, which can generate the `INSERT` statement for you. Then you can call [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to execute that `INSERT` statement, like so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##Totals;
SELECT TOP 0 email, country, revenue -- Hack to let SQL Server build the structure of the temp table for you 
INTO ##Totals
FROM total_0122;

DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @DynamicSQL = 
    STRING_AGG
    (
     CONCAT
     (
      'SELECT email, country, revenue
       FROM ', [name],
      'UNION ALL'
     ),
     CONCAT(CHAR(10), CHAR(13))
    )
FROM sys.tables
WHERE [name] LIKE '%total_%';

SET @DynamicSQL = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ##Totals', CONCAT(CHAR(10), CHAR(13)), @DyanmicSQL);

-- PRINT @DynamicSQL; -- For verifying correct syntax was generated

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL;
```

One caveat you'll notice is I'm hard-coding the column names and only using `sys.tables` to get me all of the tables. I figured this was ok since you'd only have to do it once, since all of the tables share the same columns. There is a way to have it automatically pull in the column names from `sys.columns` too, by using `PIVOT` but would be more verbose, probably more work than it's worth, and I'm typing this up on my phone, so this is where I tap out.

Also note the above uses [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) which is only available on SQL Server 2017 or later (hopefully you're using a modern version, otherwise you'll need to use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` which is just not fun). Best of luck!